# How to install snapcraft in a BBB running snappy 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, ubuntu-core, snap

When I try to install snapcraft is that occurs:
(BeagleBoneBlack)ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo snappy install snapcraft
Installing snapcraft
snapcraft failed to install: snappy package not found

Answer (score 1):

Snapcraft is a tool to create snaps and not a snap by itself. If you wish to develop snaps for BBB, install docker and than instantiate an ubuntu container. Follow the tutorial below and install snapcraft-

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/get-started/

Comment: In this tutorial is used the follow commands:
(BeagleBoneBlack)ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:snappy-dev/tools

sudo: apt-add-repository: command not found

(BeagleBoneBlack)ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo apt update

Ubuntu Core does not use apt-get, see 'snappy --help'!

What means "instantiate an ubuntu container"?

I already have Docker installed.

Comment: The tutorial is for traditional Ubuntu. If you have the docker snap installed, than you can instantiate an ubuntu container using- `docker pull ubuntu` and `docker run -it armbuild/ubuntu:latest`